# Are dynamically created script executed outside of document parsing?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, rendering, createelement

Are dynamically created script executed outside of document parsing?

See: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

About dynamically created scripts, the author is saying:

> However, by being dynamically created, they’re executed outside of document parsing, so rendering isn’t blocked while they’re downloaded

Now check this example:

INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        ['script.js'].forEach( function( src ) {
            var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
            script.src = src;
            script.async = true;
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });

        // Some other javascript execution, let's say execution delay of 2 seconds.
        var timeWhile = new Date().getTime(); 
        while( new Date().getTime() - timeWhile < 2000 );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a1">a1</div>
    <div id="a2">a2</div>
    <div id="a3">a3</div>
    <div id="a4">a4</div>
    <div id="a5">a5</div>
    <div id="a6">a6</div>
    <div id="a7">a7</div>
    <div id="a8">a8</div>
    <div id="a9">a9</div>
    <div id="a10">a10</div>
    <div id="a11">a11</div>
    <div id="a12">a12</div>
    <div id="a13">a13</div>
    <div id="a14">a14</div>
    <div id="a15">a15</div>
    <div id="a16">a16</div>
    <div id="a17">a17</div>
    <div id="a18">a18</div>
    <div id="a19">a19</div>
    <div id="a20">a20</div>
    <div id="a21">a21</div>
    <div id="a22">a22</div>
    <div id="a23">a23</div>
    <div id="a24">a24</div>
    <div id="a25">a25</div>
    <div id="a26">a26</div>
    <div id="a27">a27</div>
    <div id="a28">a28</div>
    <div id="a29">a29</div>
    <div id="a30">a30</div>
    <div id="a31">a31</div>
    <div id="a32">a32</div>
    <div id="a33">a33</div>
    <div id="a34">a34</div>
    <div id="a35">a35</div>
    <div id="a36">a36</div>
    <div id="a37">a37</div>
    <div id="a38">a38</div>
    <div id="a39">a39</div>
    <div id="a40">a40</div>
    <div id="a41">a41</div>
    <div id="a42">a42</div>
    <div id="a43">a43</div>
    <div id="a44">a44</div>
    <div id="a45">a45</div>
    <div id="a46">a46</div>
    <div id="a47">a47</div>
    <div id="a48">a48</div>
    <div id="a49">a49</div>
    <div id="a50">a50</div>

    <script>
        alert('We are half way...');
    </script>

    <div id="a51">a51</div>
    <div id="a52">a52</div>
    <div id="a53">a53</div>
    <div id="a54">a54</div>
    <div id="a55">a55</div>
    <div id="a56">a56</div>
    <div id="a57">a57</div>
    <div id="a58">a58</div>
    <div id="a59">a59</div>
    <div id="a60">a60</div>
    <div id="a61">a61</div>
    <div id="a62">a62</div>
    <div id="a63">a63</div>
    <div id="a64">a64</div>
    <div id="a65">a65</div>
    <div id="a66">a66</div>
    <div id="a67">a67</div>
    <div id="a68">a68</div>
    <div id="a69">a69</div>
    <div id="a70">a70</div>
    <div id="a71">a71</div>
    <div id="a72">a72</div>
    <div id="a73">a73</div>
    <div id="a74">a74</div>
    <div id="a75">a75</div>
    <div id="a76">a76</div>
    <div id="a77">a77</div>
    <div id="a78">a78</div>
    <div id="a79">a79</div>
    <div id="a80">a80</div>
    <div id="a81">a81</div>
    <div id="a82">a82</div>
    <div id="a83">a83</div>
    <div id="a84">a84</div>
    <div id="a85">a85</div>
    <div id="a86">a86</div>
    <div id="a87">a87</div>
    <div id="a88">a88</div>
    <div id="a89">a89</div>
    <div id="a90">a90</div>
    <div id="a91">a91</div>
    <div id="a92">a92</div>
    <div id="a93">a93</div>
    <div id="a94">a94</div>
    <div id="a95">a95</div>
    <div id="a96">a96</div>
    <div id="a97">a97</div>
    <div id="a98">a98</div>
    <div id="a99">a99</div>
    <div id="a100">a100</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT.JS

```
// Count divs, followed by a synchronous delay of 1 second
console.log( 'COUNT DIVS:' + document.body.getElementsByTagName( 'div' ).length );
var timeWhile = new Date().getTime(); 
while( new Date().getTime() - timeWhile < 1000 );

// Count divs, followed by a synchronous delay of 1 second
console.log( 'COUNT DIVS:' + document.body.getElementsByTagName( 'div' ).length );
var timeWhile = new Date().getTime(); 
while( new Date().getTime() - timeWhile < 1000 );

// Synchronous delay of 500 milliseconds, followed by counting the amount of divs
setTimeout( function() {
    console.log( 'COUNT DIVS:' + document.body.getElementsByTagName( 'div' ).length );
}, 500 );
```

Of course this is not a real life example, but the structure is based on a real life page of mine. I only used this example to make it more clear.

You can do the test by yourself here: https://dynamically-created-script.glitch.me/

The console.log will show something like:

COUNT DIVS:50

COUNT DIVS:50

COUNT DIVS:100

This means the execution of script.js took place when the "HTML parser" was about half the page. The execution of script.js will block the "html parser" and "rendering" during execution.

Now go back to the quote from the article:

> However, by being dynamically created, they’re executed outside of document parsing, so rendering isn’t blocked while they’re downloaded

I don't know what they mean with: the script will be "executed outside of document parsing"

Execution of JavaScript will always pause the "HTML parser", so if the author meant it like that, then there was no need to mention it. So what he could mean? Or is he just wrong?
Anyway i know the DOWNLOAD of script.js will not block rendering, but that's not because of: the execution will take place outside of document parsing. As you can see in my example, the execution will delay rendering.

And of course you can find examples where the "HTML parser" or "rendering" already has been finished, before the execution of script.js starts. But there are also plenty examples where that's not the case.

So how i have to see that sentence? I know how it's working, but that's why i don't understand why he is using a sentence like that. If i would be a newbie, i would think after reading it, that script.js would be executed after "HTML parser" is done (same as with defer).